# jQuery checkbox value bug (?)

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm creating and append to some element some checbox. After that, if I want the value of checked checbox, I have problem:

```
$('#step-1').find('.checkbox').live('click', function() {
    alert($(this).attr('val')); // return correct value
    alert($(this).val()); // return strong 'no'
});
```

Comment: What's the question here?  What bug?

Comment: You really need to improve your accept ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `this.value`:

```
$('#step-1').find('.checkbox').live('click', function() {
    if(this.checked){ //if the checkbox is checked
        alert(this.value);
    } 
    else {}
});
```

Comment: I don't understand what the actual problem is, but you should better bind to the `change` event.

Comment: No change, I am using jQuery 1.6.

Comment: val() return string 'no' instead of correct value. If I use attr('val') it's return correct value of checkbox.

Comment: Why do you think jQuery 1.6 doesn't support the 'change' event?